# WSO2 Enterprise Integrator difference between v6.6.0 and v7.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-micro-integrator, wso2-esb

I am asking about the difference between the two versions because i can not see the integrator in 7.0

Comment: the integrator is WSO2 Enterprise Service Bus (ESB)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enterprise Integrator 7.0 is the next generation of WSO2 Integration platform and mainly focuses on micro-service architecture and cloud-native architecture. This integration platform mainly offers a code-driven approach to integration development. Kindly note that the development of EI 6.x series is still being continued. EI 6xx series are for those who are familiar with existing Enterprise Integrator. For more details you can refer the documentation here. https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/micro-integrator/references/comparisong-mi7-ei6xx/

Integrator is available in EI 7.0 as Micro Integrator.

This blog describes the difference between WSO2 6xx and 7xx. (Evolution of Micro Integrator) https://medium.com/arunans23/life-of-mi-how-an-esb-went-on-to-serve-microservices-9bb4faed5588

Comment: Thank you Arunan for your answer.